# create an array of access to textures in shader in vulkan?

Tags: textures, vulkan

I'm rewriting my rust game engine, integrating Vulkan. I have a little graphic programming background with openGL, but I'm a Vulkan beginner. I'm both doing this to be able to develop games on top of the engine, and for learning purposes.

I'm trying to optimize it to render hundreds of thousands of objects.

I'm currently doing instance rendering, and my uniforms are buffers accessed with gl_InstanceIndex in the shader. In my material system, material properties are a color and a texture, stored as 3 f32 (color) and u32 (texture index). So I have the texture index in the shader, now I would like to pass an array of samplers to my shader to access the texture at the specific index. I want to avoid looping through my objects and binding their textures one by one, because I want my materials to be independant of my meshes (different objects can have the same mesh but different materials / textures) and with my current set up I'm only binding descriptor sets per frame.

I created a library of textures, with each textures having it's own index, but now I'm struggling to find a way to create an array of samplers, targetting my textures, and passing those with a single descriptor set each frame.

I'm still struggling between the different objects for texture manipulation, like Image, Image view, Sampler, Combined sampler etc.

Of course, I can provide further information about my architecture.

TLDR; I was wondering, is it possible to have an array (buffer ?) of samplers, and access it from a shader like I do with my other uniforms (instead of the instance id, using the texture id from the material) ? How could I achieve that ?

Comment: You achieve that by... *doing that*. It's directly supported in both the Vulkan API and the shader language. You make an array of samplers in your shader, and a descriptor that is an array of samplers.

Comment: @NicolBolas could you give more details / resources ? I've been struggling for both of those. Especially for setting up an array of samplers in my shader, I'll always have the error "member of block cannot be or contain a sampler, image, or atomic_uint type"

Comment: You would get the same error if it *weren't* an array. You can't put samplers inside of a uniform/SSBO block, whether arrayed or not. An array of samplers is just a sampler variable... that is an *array*. You know, with `[length]` syntax.